# Darts how to build Timeseries - ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, u8darts

I'm using DARTS to run forecasting model

I have two columns:

```
TIME, QUANTITY
```

value is allocated quarterly with missing value.

```
2006-01-01  13.0
2006-04-01   2.0
2007-0-01   3.0
2007-10-01  11.0
```

I want to build Timeseries

```
_df.index = _df[TIME]

series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(_df, 
                                   #time_col=TIME, 
                                   value_cols=[QUANTITY], 
                                   freq='Q',
                                   fill_missing_dates=True)

series = fill_missing_values(series=series, fill=0.0)
```

and I got

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
_can_reindex(self, indexer)    3281         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates    3282         if not self.is_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3283             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")    3284     3285     def reindex(self, target, method=None, level=None, limit=None, tolerance=None):

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

also removing comment

```
time_col=TIME,
```

I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using pandas interpolation

```
_df.index = _df[c_time]
#_df = _df[c_quantity]
_df = _df.resample('Q').sum().interpolate(method='time')
```